# How to update driver to play Angry Birds on Lenovo SL400?

Tags: angry-birds

I got this error when starting game:
"Texture is too large: 2048x2048, maximum supported size: 1024x1024."

I googled some hours and find a solution out: updating display adapters in Device Management.
My display adapter is Mobile Intel(R) 45 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1). When I updated it, it reported "your device is up to date". Now I still can't play the game.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Intel has a guide to solve this problem on their homepage](http://www.intel.com/support/software/stores/appupwn/sb/CS-032248.htm). According to this you need to perform the following steps:

> - Update your video driver. Check with your computer/graphics card
>     manufacture for the latest driver.
> - Set your graphics video hardware acceleration in the middle between
>     Full & None.
> - Confirm your driver supports OpenGL* 1.3+. OpenGL* 1.3+ is required to run Angry Birds.

If you're sure you have the newest driver, try the second steop and set the hardware acceleration to a lower level.

Comment: Thank you for the link.
"Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator (GMA) 500 does NOT Support OpenGL* 2.0. Some Intel® Atom™ based systems use the Mobile Intel® 945 Express Chipset Family which uses the GMA500".

My display adapter is Mobile Intel® 45 Express Chipset Family, I think I can't play this game. :(

Answer (score 1):

Angry Birds works with Intel express 45.  Just updated the drivers on a friend's computer with the same chipset and now A.B. works fine.

Another fix I heard, but not sure if it works is editing the 'config' file.  Change fullscreen to 'false' and resolution to 800x600 in the config file.

If after updating it still doesn't work and the resolution fix doesn't work, you can play the first set of levels for free through Google Chrome.  Install Chrome and go to their appstore.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Lenovo's [downloads page](http://download.lenovo.com/lenovo/content/ddfm/MIGR-70413.html) for your specific system (search for "Intel Display Driver" on the page).

According to it, the last driver update is 2009, which is a bit outdated, but you could still try that and see if it helps.

Comment: I use Win7 and its video driver seems to be built-in. Anyway, thank you.